# Mapping float ** to Eigen::MatrixXf

Tags: c++, eigen

please how can i map float** to Eigen::MatrixXf?

This function is the Empirical Mode Decomposition of EEG signals. the problem is that i cant map the output of the EMD to `eigen::MatrixXf` cause it is `float**`

```
std::vector <Eigen::MatrixXf> EMD (Eigen::MatrixXd array, int order, int iterations, int locality) {
    std::vector <Eigen::MatrixXf> IMFs;
emdData IMF;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.rows(); i++) {
        Eigen::MatrixXd Kanals = array.row(i);

        const float* signal = (float*)Kanals.data();

        emdCreate(&IMF, Kanals.cols(), order, iterations, locality);
        emdDecompose(&IMF, signal);

        float** IMFd = IMF.imfs;

        //int arrSize = sizeof(IMFd) / sizeof(IMFd[0][0]);
        //std::cout << "Its Size: " << IMF.size << " arrSize: " << arrSize << " Min: " << IMF.minSize << " Max: " << IMF.maxSize<<"\n";
        
        Eigen::MatrixXf  Out_IMF = Eigen::Map <Eigen::MatrixXf> (*IMFd, IMF.minSize, IMF.maxSize);

        IMFs.push_back(Out_IMF);
    }
    return IMFs;
}
```

Comment: What's `emdData`? `Eigen::Map` expects a 1D array, not the first row of a 2D array

Comment: This is the Emirical Mode Decomposition Object: https://code.google.com/archive/p/realtime-emd/downloads

Comment: Can you edit the question to include an explanation of `emdData`? Like how it lays out `imfs` and what `minSize` and `maxSize` correspond to?

Comment: please how can i make all the data of float** in 1D array?

Comment: That depends on how it is laid out. The most general way would to be copy it, at which point you may as well copy it into a `Eigen::MatrixXf`

Comment: so if i copy it to `std::vector <float> X` `X.push_back(IMFd[i][j])` in a for loop could it work?

Comment: No, `Out_IMF[i][j] = IMF.imfs[i][j]`

Comment: Thank you it have worked fine but i am not sure of the size of `float** IMFd` please is there a way to get it's size.

Comment: Presumably that's what `minSize` and `maxSize` are?

Comment: I am affraid that they are not the right parameters.